# Python - Sum of the factorials

Tags: python, algorithm

```
B=0
A=1
m=int(input("input a number please "))
for k in range (1,m+1) :
    for i in range (1,k+1) :
    A=i*A
    B=B+A
print("this is your number",B)
```

if i type 4 ,this gives me 418 , it's supposed to give me 32, what am i doing wrong here?

I've tried everything to correct it

Edit : this to calculate the sum of factorials , if i type 4 it will calculate 1! + 2! + 3! + 4!

Comment: 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! = 33 not 32

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reset `A` to 1 before the i loop. The correct answer should be:

```
B=0
A=1
m=int(input("input a number please "))
for k in range (1,m+1):
    A=1
    for i in range (1,k+1):
        A=i*A
    B=B+A
print("this is your number",B)
```

Comment: sadly this dosent give th e correct answer , for example i typed 4 and it gave me 46 , it should give 33 (4! + 3! + 2! +1

Comment: sorry I forgot to re indent the `B=B+A` line. Basically you would need to do this once for every factorial

Comment: thank you , this worked , i didn't pay attention to the importance of that

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You can use:

```
math.factorial(x)
```

Initialize a sum with `0`, use a for loop and add the result of the above line to the sum:

```
from math import factorial
s=0
m=4
for k in range (1,m+1) :
    s=s+factorial(k)
print (s)
```

**Solution 2**

Manually:

```
s=0
m=4
for i in range(1,m+1):
    p=1
    for k in range(1,i+1):
        p*=k
    s+=p
print (s)
```

Comment: sorry but im trying to learn without using functions , a friend of mine recomonned this

Answer (score 0):

or you could try:

```
partial_sum = 0
current_factorial = 1
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
  current_factorial *= i
  partial_sum += current_factorial
print(partial_sum)
```