# How to do a sum of chosen Factorial Numbers?

Tags: python, numbers, factorial

```
while (4>0) :

    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2=int(input("Enter 2nd Number"))

    for i in range(num,num2+1):
       factorial = 1
       factorialsum = 0
       for y in range(1,i+1):
           factorial = factorial*i
       factorialsum =factorial+factorialsum
    print(factorialsum)
```

I've tried to move it around, but it never seems to work. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Sum of the factorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727548/python-sum-of-the-factorials)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Also indent your code correctly so i can replicate it and assist.

Comment: Why `4 > 0`? Why not `2 > 0` or `3 > 0` or, you know, `True`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
def factorial(x):
   if x <= 1:
     return x
   return x * factorial(x - 1)

def factorialSum(start, end):
   sum = 0
   for x in range(start, end + 1):
      sum += factorial(x)
   return sum

n1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n2 = int(input("Enter 2nd Number: "))

if n2 < n1:
   print "The second number should be greather than first number"
else:
   print(factorialSum(n1, n2))
```